# Shorthand for "has property..."

Tags: notation

Is the mathematical shorthand for the phrase "has the property..." or "satisfies the condition..."? As in, when you have a set of properties or conditions predefined, how can you write that an object has those properties or satisfies those conditions?

For example, in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, in the Appendix to "The Real and Complex Number Systems," Rudin defines three properties, (I), (II), and (III) that define a cut. Later on, he tries to prove that various sets satisfy these conditions and are therefore cuts. In Step 3, for instance, he defines a set $\gamma$, then proves that this set satisfies (I), (II), and (III) and is therefore a cut. Is there any symbolic notation for "$\gamma$ satisfies (I)" ?

Thanks

Comment: I usually go with *fulfills* but I am not a native English speaker, so you should not trust me too much.

Comment: If the "property" $S$ is defined for some sort of "objects" and $\gamma$ is such kind of object, then $S(\gamma)$ will do. If $\text {Even}$ is defined for *natural* numbers, we can write: $\text {Even} (2)$.

Comment: The short answer is no, especially for a situation with roman numerals like you quoted. But in mathematical logic there is a related, if more formal notion, of a model satisfying a statement (or set of statements) in some language; there we would write $\mathcal{M}\vDash \Gamma$. But no one would use this turnstile notation in the course of ordinary mathematical writing like the sort you quote from Rudin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never stumbled across some standard, agreed-upon terminology. If you want to make it formal, you make the property a set $S$, and to say "$\gamma$ satisfies [the property]", you say $\gamma \in S$.

If you want formal, universally understood terminology, making the property a set is the way to go. If you want easily human-readable text, then substituting symbols, shorthand, or jargon in for phrases is not advisable. If you want succinct, often defining a set does not require much more space than defining the property itself.